# What's this red cabin light indicator inside a Boeing 737?

Tags: boeing-737, cabin-design

What's this red light indicator inside the cabin, its flush with the sides of the plane. The exact location would be a couple of rows ahead of the overwing exit seats.

This picture was taken before take-off. Forgot to observe the light after take-off. This is not a flight-attendant call indicator.

[image]

Comment: Was there anything similar on the opposite side of the cabin?

Comment: @MichaelKjörling No, there was no light on the opposite side of the cabin, It may have been off, that I cannot confirm. I did look on the other side to see if there was a red light there as well.

Comment: Kinda looks like one of the lights for the cabin "mood lighting" is not working correctly. Those side lights can be red, blue, green, etc. but they are normally all the same color. Like [this](http://www.sjap.nl/images/sky2.jpg)

Comment: @TomMcW It wasn't 'mood lighting', it appeared to me more as an indicator, in the sense, I could see a similar indicator type section which is near the lavatory.

Comment: It might be there for the emergency exit; but other than I have no idea.

Comment: This is not an answer (so not posting it as such), but I seem to recall a question/answer here at some point in the past that may be related.  I apologize but could not find it again.  I believe on some aircraft there are interior markings to indicate to the crew at a glance which window(s) are optimal for looking outside to have a good view of the front of the engines in case a rapid visual inspection is needed.  Could this be some sort of indicator of such, since it appears to be right above a window in approximately the right place to look at the front of the B737 engines?

Comment: @Milwrdfan I remember the question you're referring to. It referred to A320, which had some kind of sticker above windows. My first thought went towards that, but I couldn't see a corresponding light on the opposite side of the cabin. Waiting for someone with actual knowledge of a 737 cabin to answer it.

Comment: @Firee since the winds are on the same spot on both sides.. and it is not a wide-body, one light would be enough.

Comment: xpost : https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/39634/what-does-this-black-triangle-placard-on-board-an-a320-denote

Comment: @Trevor: I know the question you have linked, I even have a comment there 4 months back.

Answer (score 4):

I found this pertaining to the new interior design of some Boeing737(s), I can only guess the coloring is from one of the mood lighting (Blue or red) has a defect in the connections.[image: enter link description here]https://www.airlines-inform.com/flight-reports/amarchukov-1754.html