# Where are the black triangle'd seats?

Tags: wing, airbus-a320, airbus, windows, seats

There are two windows marked with a black triangle, which indicate that they provide the best view for the wing, when the crew needs visual.

Since A320s are probably the most popular birds out there nowadays, in which row are these best-view windows?

It would be nice to take that seat when I check-in in my next flight.

Comment: [What does this black triangle placard on board an A320 denote?](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/q/39634/3201)

Comment: Row 9 then @mins, thanks and sorry for failing to find the dupe earlier.

Comment: Doesn't that depend on the seat configuration ordered by the company buying the aircraft?

Comment: @αCVn probably you are right, but it should be somewhere nearby... ;)

Comment: I wrote a real nice answer to this, went to click post, and found out you closed it..

Comment: @Matt I am really sorry, but I didn't have a clue. I now see that I cannot reopen the question by myself, it needs votes, etc...

Comment: Whelp, here it is in a pastebin - Note that it shows the triangle seat is *not* the best seat for passenger viewing. 

https://pastebin.com/v7bG0Uic - I'll wait for the day the question "Is the triangle-marked seat best for passenger view?" pops up! :)

Comment: Not a dupe but maybe off topic.

Comment: @vasin1987 Not a duplicate, though the answer can be gleaned from the linked topic. A question such as "Which seat has the best view on an A320" is most certainly not offtopic.